# Setting up DFP for Mobile and Desktop - Line Item targeting

Tags: google-dfp, prebid.js

I was wondering, our desktop setup is already done so the dfp key `hb_pb`  for desktop can not be changed anymore

So the price targeting for `hb_pb` is returning a third party creative with this code:

```
<script>
var w = window;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  w = w.parent;
  if (w.pbjs) {
    try {
      w.pbjs.renderAd(document, '%%PATTERN:hb_adid%%');
      break;
    } catch (e) {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

However the mobile setup requires this creative:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "//acdn.adnxs.com/mobile/prebid/pbm.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    pbm.showAdFromCacheId({
        admCacheID : '%%PATTERN:hb_cache_id%%'
    });
</script>
```

Now the problem is that both setups use `hb_pb` as their targeting.

Is there any way to set the targeting key that Prebid **Mobile** is sending to DFP?

Comment: As a note: I'm using prebid.adnxs.com (AppNexus) for mobile server side bidding - so assumably the targeting key has to be set in there? Maybe as a config parameter?

Comment: You'd be a good candidate for the prebid universal creative. https://github.com/prebid/prebid-universal-creative the mobile portion is in code review.

Comment: So how did you solve the issue?